# Get https://gcp.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to push my docker image to Google Cloud Registry but get a 509 error say the certificate signed by unknown authority. This never used to be a problem and I can't seem to fix the issue. Any help is appreciated.

**I'm running**

`docker -- push gcp.io/project/registry`

**Error**

`Get https://gcp.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I'm on Mac OS.

Comment: Please include the command being run, the entire output from that command, and a description of the environment where you are running the command.

Comment: @BMitch Just Updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: you have a typo, you need to go to `gcr.io`, not `gcp.io`.

---

[ Original answer ]

Looks like a certificate issue on gcp.io:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect gcp.io:443 </dev/null    
CONNECTED(00000003)                                             
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.gcp.io
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate      
verify return:1                                                 
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.gcp.io
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate      
verify return:1                                                 
---                                                             
Certificate chain                                               
 0 s:OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.gcp.io
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----                                     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-----END CERTIFICATE-----               
 1 s:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----                                     
MIIFdzCCBF+gAwIBAgIQE+oocFv07O0MNmMJgGFDNjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADBv
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTEUMBIGA1UEChMLQWRkVHJ1c3QgQUIxJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFk   
ZFRydXN0IEV4dGVybmFsIFRUUCBOZXR3b3JrMSIwIAYDVQQDExlBZGRUcnVzdCBF
eHRlcm5hbCBDQSBSb290MB4XDTAwMDUzMDEwNDgzOFoXDTIwMDUzMDEwNDgzOFow
gYgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpOZXcgSmVyc2V5MRQwEgYDVQQHEwtK
ZXJzZXkgQ2l0eTEeMBwGA1UEChMVVGhlIFVTRVJUUlVTVCBOZXR3b3JrMS4wLAYD
VQQDEyVVU0VSVHJ1c3QgUlNBIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MIICIjAN
BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAgBJlFzYOw9sIs9CsVw127c0n00yt
UINh4qogTQktZAnczomfzD2p7PbPwdzx07HWezcoEStH2jnGvDoZtF+mvX2do2NC
tnbyqTsrkfjib9DsFiCQCT7i6HTJGLSR1GJk23+jBvGIGGqQIjy8/hPwhxR79uQf
jtTkUcYRZ0YIUcuGFFQ/vDP+fmyc/xadGL1RjjWmp2bIcmfbIWax1Jt4A8BQOujM
8Ny8nkz+rwWWNR9XWrf/zvk9tyy29lTdyOcSOk2uTIq3XJq0tyA9yn8iNK5+O2hm
AUTnAU5GU5szYPeUvlM3kHND8zLDU+/bqv50TmnHa4xgk97Exwzf4TKuzJM7UXiV
Z4vuPVb+DNBpDxsP8yUmazNt925H+nND5X4OpWaxKXwyhGNVicQNwZNUMBkTrNN9
N6frXTpsNVzbQdcS2qlJC9/YgIoJk2KOtWbPJYjNhLixP6Q5D9kCnusSTJV882sF
qV4Wg8y4Z+LoE53MW4LTTLPtW//e5XOsIzstAL81VXQJSdhJWBp/kjbmUZIO8yZ9
HE0XvMnsQybQv0FfQKlERPSZ51eHnlAfV1SoPv10Yy+xUGUJ5lhCLkMaTLTwJUdZ
+gQek9QmRkpQgbLevni3/GcV4clXhB4PY9bpYrrWX1Uu6lzGKAgEJTm4Diup8kyX
HAc/DVL17e8vgg8CAwEAAaOB9DCB8TAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBStvZh6NLQm9/rEJlTv
A73gJMtUGjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUU3m/WqorSs9UgOHYm8Cd8rIDZsswDgYDVR0PAQH/
BAQDAgGGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wEQYDVR0gBAowCDAGBgRVHSAAMEQGA1Ud
HwQ9MDswOaA3oDWGM2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwudXNlcnRydXN0LmNvbS9BZGRUcnVzdEV4
dGVybmFsQ0FSb290LmNybDA1BggrBgEFBQcBAQQpMCcwJQYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGWh0
dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnVzZXJ0cnVzdC5jb20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQADggEBAJNl9jeD
lQ9ew4IcH9Z35zyKwKoJ8OkLJvHgwmp1ocd5yblSYMgpEg7wrQPWCcR23+WmgZWn
RtqCV6mVksW2jwMibDN3wXsyF24HzloUQToFJBv2FAY7qCUkDrvMKnXduXBBP3zQ
YzYhBx9G/2CkkeFnvN4ffhkUyWNnkepnB2u0j4vAbkN9w6GAbLIevFOFfdyQoaS8
Le9Gclc1Bb+7RrtubTeZtv8jkpHGbkD4jylW6l/VXxRTrPBPYer3IsynVgviuDQf
Jtl7GQVoP7o81DgGotPmjw7jtHFtQELFhLRAlSv0ZaBIefYdgWOWnU914Ph85I6p
0fKtirOMxyHNwu8=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.gcp.io

issuer=C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3435 bytes and written 424 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: A1FB2B7B405094705F0DAFCAABA63B4E1ABDE5C122F2F3E5A7DE88ECB75AB617
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: A0FB112FC9A33BD96E2346627A4E99A03F5C8AA404B19215EA3226A487B034E17EAC38AE0BD79C6B51E882BDC0DECE90
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1588527367
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
DONE
```

And I see a similar error from `curl -v https://gcp.io/v2/`. This will need to be resolved by Google.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Maybe with self signed cert?

Comment: Google should be using a valid certificate for hosting a service like this. This is either an outage that recently started, or I'm mistaken in my analysis, because I can't find anyone else commenting about it yet.

Comment: Yea I'm finding it hard to believe it's a google issue. What can I check on my end to make sure I have the correct things setup?

Comment: See the update at the top of my answer, you're pointing to the wrong server.